# Laravel make manual password reset

Tags: laravel, password-recovery

I am working in laravel,
I am stuck in reset password manually,
I verify the mail is exist in database or not if mail is exist than it will redirect to reset password page.

When user type the password and submit the form, at that time password is not update in mongoDb database.

here's my function...

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function confirmPassword(Request $request, $email)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
        ]);


        $admin = AdminAuth::find($email);
        $admin->password = $request->get('password');

        $admin->save();
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

Comment: need to hash plain password. `$admin->password = bycrypt($request->get('password'));`

Comment: do you try to debug using `dd($admin)` before save?

Comment: yes, it shows nothing,
Direct redirect me on home page.

Comment: @John_rees this means that code for save password is never executed. You shoul debug your code and find reason

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$admin->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
```

More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing). And remember: never save users passwords explicit in db.